# retornar view com model vazio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu faço o submit para salvar, e quero que ele retorne na mesma view, mas com os campos vazios, um model novo, pra ele poder adicionar novamente

Mas ele sempre volta já com os dados que preenchi

Minha action está assim:

```
public ActionResult SalvarNovo(grupoViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Grupo entity = new Grupo();
    Mapper.Map(model, entity);

    grupocService.Adiciona(entity);
  }
  return View("Novo");
}
```

Como faço para ele retornar vazio os campos? ou direcionar para essa view novamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que essa `SalvarNovo` é o action de `submit` do `form` você simplesmente redireciona o usuário para a `action` que gera a `view` do formulário.

```
return RedirectToAction("nome da action que gera o formulario");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `RedirectToAction`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Novo");
```